# Updating a section of the webpage without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I am implementing a website using Django. I searched online about updating a section of the webpage without refreshing the whole page but those don't work for me, probably because the part(div) I want to update is actually implemented by javascript(using script to include in html). The only thing I updated is a variable in the script and this result should be reflected on the website. Here is my code in the main.html

```
# I first have a button that could be clicked
<div class="col-lg-4">
     <p><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="display_list" id="display_list">Display List</button></p>
</div>
# here is the script I include to update the section without refreshing the whole page
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#display_list").click(function(){
            $.get("display_list/", function(ret){
                $('#result').html(ret);
             });
          });
        });
</script>
```

And I have the code of the section I want to update in a separate html file(show_result.html):

```
<div id="result">
<script> javascript that draws a graph on html webpage. I pass the updated variable from the corresponding function in views.py to here by calling render(). </script>
</div>
```

Here is my function in the views.py:

```
def display_list(request):
    #some function implementation to get the result and put it in context
    return render(request, "show_result.html",context)
```

And this is the code in my url file:

```
url(r'^display_list/$', views.display_list, name='display_list'),
```

I could provide more information if needed. But I don't see why whenever I click the button, the graph appends to the original webpage instead of updating it in the same place. How could I modify so that that section is refreshed instead of appended to the original page?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove  `id="result"` from your html `show_result.html` because once you load it the first time your html will be like this

```
<div id="result">
  <div id="result">
     <script> javascript that draws a graph on html webpage. I pass the updated variable from the corresponding function in views.py to here by calling render(). </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is not valid html to have multiple items with the same `id`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why is there two `<div id="result">`? I only defined it once at the beginning of the html file. And if I just say `<div>`, how could this line of code in main.html(`$('#result').html(ret);`) work?

Comment: I tried and did `<div>` instead. But that part of graph didn't refresh itself when I clicked the button. It is only refreshed when I refresh the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that in your main.html, there is no div with id="result".
You need to put it because the js below will be looking for it.

```
$('#result').html(ret);
```

So just put this inside the main.html

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Another way is to edit this

```
$('#result').html(ret);
```

to this

```
$('#display_list').html(ret);
```

Comment: I tried both of them but they were still appending to the original page instead of updating the page. I don't understand why they were appending instead of updating that section of the page.

Comment: It will update only the result div and not the whole page. That's what ajax is for.